# Captured multiple photos from camera does not set on imageview - Samsung S3 issue

Tags: android, camera, imageview, android-camera

Its been 5 days now and no one to help!! please can anyone help me

I have a problem and that persists specially for Samsumg S3 phones only. 
I am trying to take 4 images from the Camera service of android.

The problem is when i am trying to do it for other phones the same code works perfectly fine, but shows problem with Samsung S3 phone.

What am i trying to do is  have 4 Imageview's, on every imageview's onclick i can open camera service or gallery service according to the users choice. Once the image is being clicked or selected, that image is set on that particular imageview which was clicked.

So i can set all 4 images one by one. This works fine with other phone and also other samsung phones but seems to have a problem with Samsung S3.

Could anyone please help me out.

Here is my code where i am taking the images on the imageView.

My Oncreate method

```
public class Add_image extends Activity {

ImageView imgview1, imgview2, imgview3, imgview4;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
String SD_CARD_IMAGE_PATH = null;
byte b[];
String largeImagePath = "";
Uri uriLargeImage;
Uri uriThumbnailImage;
private static final int OG = 4;
int flag = 0, orientation;
String bal, picturePath, bal1, bal2, bal3, bal4;
int flagg = 0;
Cursor myCursor, cursor1;
Bitmap thumbnail = null; 
TextView t5, t6, t7, t8;
// SharedPreferences pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4;

Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
    imgview1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgview1.setOnClickListener(click_img1);

    imgview2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imgview2.setOnClickListener(click_img2);

    imgview3 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imgview3.setOnClickListener(click_img3);

    imgview4 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imgview4.setOnClickListener(click_img4);
    t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    t5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    t6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    t7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    t7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    t8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    t8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(btn_click);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        Bitmap carpic;
        String B1 = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
        // Toast.makeText(this, "SavedYeah"+B1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = OG;

        carpic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((B1), opts);
        System.gc();
        if (carpic != null) {

            imageCam(carpic);
        }

    }

}
```

different button clicks

```
public View.OnClickListener btn_click = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Add_image.this, Add.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};

private View.OnClickListener click_img1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = 1;
        openNewGameDialog();

    }
};
private View.OnClickListener click_img2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = 2;
        openNewGameDialog();

    }
};
private View.OnClickListener click_img3 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = 3;
        openNewGameDialog();

    }
};
private View.OnClickListener click_img4 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = 4;
        openNewGameDialog();

    }
};
```

My openNewGameDialog() method to check the Manufacturer and the Camera Service

```
String[] B = { "Camera", "Gallery", "Delete Image" };

private void openNewGameDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(B,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        String BX1 = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

                        if (BX1.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")) {
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "Device man"+BX1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent,
                                    CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        } else {
                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                    CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                        }
                    }

                    else if (i == 1) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        if (flag == 1) {
                            imgview1.setImageDrawable(null);
                            t5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (flag == 2) {
                            imgview2.setImageDrawable(null);
                            t7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (flag == 3) {
                            imgview3.setImageDrawable(null);
                            t6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (flag == 4) {
                            imgview4.setImageDrawable(null);
                            t8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }).show();
}
```

imageCam() Method the set the Images to the ImageView

```
public void imageCam(Bitmap thumbnail) {

    Bitmap photo = thumbnail;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);

    b = bos.toByteArray();
    bal = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
    // ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    String BX1 = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (BX1.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung") && flagg == 0) {

    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        bal1 = bal;

        t5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgview1.setImageBitmap(photo);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image1=" + bal1,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (flag == 2) {
        bal2 = bal;

        t7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgview2.setImageBitmap(photo);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image2=" + bal2,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (flag == 3) {
        bal3 = bal;

        t6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgview3.setImageBitmap(photo);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image3=" + bal3,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (flag == 4) {
        bal4 = bal;

        t8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgview4.setImageBitmap(photo);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image4=" + bal4,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Add ad = new Add();
    ad.image_save(bal1, bal2, bal3, bal4);
    // flag=0;

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("message", largeImagePath);
    outState.putString("Gallerymessage", picturePath);

}
```

onActivityResult() Method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        flagg = 0;
        // Describe the columns you'd like to have returned. Selecting from
        // the Thumbnails location gives you both the Thumbnail Image ID, as
        // well as the original image ID
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + // Select
                                                                        // only
                                                                        // mini's
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

        String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

        // At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL
        // images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way to
        // narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is currently
        // the selection variable
        myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selection, null, sort);

        long imageId = 0l;
        long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
        String thumbnailPath = "";

        try {

            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            imageId = myCursor
                    .getLong(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
            thumbnailImageId = myCursor
                    .getLong(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
            thumbnailPath = myCursor
                    .getString(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
        } finally {
            // myCursor.close();
        }

        // Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

        String[] largeFileProjection = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

        String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
        myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
        largeImagePath = "";

        try {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();

            // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the
            // image.
            largeImagePath = myCursor
                    .getString(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
        } finally {

            // myCursor.close();
        }
        // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give you a
        // handle to the actual images
        uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                String.valueOf(imageId));
        uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

        // I've left out the remaining code, as all I do is assign the URI's
        // to my own objects anyways...
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+largeImagePath,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriLargeImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriThumbnailImage,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (largeImagePath != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "LARGE YES" + largeImagePath,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = OG;
            // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((largeImagePath), opts);
            Bitmap bitmap = thumbnail;
            System.gc();

            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(largeImagePath);

                orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

                Log.e("ExifInteface .........", "rotation =" + orientation);

                // exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90,
                // 90);

                Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
                Matrix m = new Matrix();

                if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
                    m.postRotate(180);
                    // m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float)
                    // bm.getHeight());
                    // if(m.preRotate(90)){
                    Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                            thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                            true);

                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    m.postRotate(90);
                    Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                            thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                            true);

                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    m.postRotate(270);
                    Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                            thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                            true);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if (thumbnail != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Try Without Saved Instance",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageCam(bitmap);
            }

        }
        if (uriLargeImage != null) {

            // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriLargeImage,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        if (uriThumbnailImage != null) {

            // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriThumbnailImage,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    if (requestCode == 1337 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        flagg = 0;
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        // if (extras!=null){
        if (extras.keySet().contains("data")) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // options.inSampleSize = 1;
            // options.inPurgeable = true;
            // options.inInputShareable = true;
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            // image(thumbnail);
            if (thumbnail != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "YES Thumbnail",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                // options.inSampleSize = 1;
                // options.inPurgeable = true;
                // options.inInputShareable = true;
                thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageCam(thumbnail);
            }

        } else {

            Uri imageURI = getIntent().getData();
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageview.setImageURI(imageURI);

            if (imageURI != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "YES Image Uri",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            // Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Picture NOt taken",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        flagg = 1;

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn,
                null, null, null);
        cursor1.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor1.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
        // cursor.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = OG;
        // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((picturePath), opts);
        System.gc();
        Bitmap bitmap = thumbnail;

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);

            orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

            Log.e("ExifInteface .........", "rotation =" + orientation);

            // exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, 90);

            Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
            Matrix m = new Matrix();

            if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
                m.postRotate(180);
                // m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float)
                // bm.getHeight());
                // if(m.preRotate(90)){
                Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                        thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                        true);

            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                m.postRotate(90);
                Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                        thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                        true);

            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                m.postRotate(270);
                Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                        thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                        true);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (thumbnail != null) {
            imageCam(bitmap);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a different picture",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    else {
        // imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbtb);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Since it's not work on S3, do you have any log output? could you paste it as well?

Comment: there are no errors at all. its just that the image is not getting displayed